# How to correctly export datetime column in SSRS to Excel

Tags: reporting-services

When I export my SSRS Report to Excel, the datetime column shows `#####` instead of datetime values (see pictures)

[image: SSRS Report]

[image: Exported to Excel]

How can I fix it?

Comment: its probably just that the column is not wide enough. Expand the column width and if you can see the data then just make the column header wider in your report

Comment: @AlanSchofield Please write it as an answer, it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its probably just that the column is not wide enough. Expand the column width and if you can see the data then just make the column header wider in your report